# String versus StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I need to modify the input string to return some output. Basically, when I see a particular string I need to remove it. I am thinking whether to use StringBuilder versus String. From my perspective, String would be much simpler.

Suppose:

```
StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder(inputs)
if(inputs.contains("someword)"")) {
     // remove it by inputs = inputs.replace("someword", "");
}
```

Is it better to use `StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder(inputs)` and delete the particular string or use the original `inputs = inputs.replace(...).`

I think it will get messy to use `StringBuilder`. `StringBuilder` is used for concatentation, but I am not concentating strings.

Comment: Why do you need to use StringBuilder then if you're not "building strings"? Internally replace code is basically the same

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri That is a C# question. Using C# questions as duplicate targets for Java questions is not really appropriate.

Comment: Accidental reference, but the idea is pretty much same.

Comment: What exactly is `inputs` plural versus `input` singular. Your Question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, `StringBuilder` was most times much faster than `String` when you applied multiple modifications to a `String`.

But since JDK 6, the compiler itself replaces `String` often automatically by `StringBuilder` (including all related lines) when this may improve the performance. This becomes visible by the use of a decompiler. So in most cases you won't notice any difference.

If you apply multiple operations to a string in a more complex structure than a simple batch of commands, then using `StringBuilder` is still better than the automatic compiler optimization.

Comment: This doesn't address the specific scenario of the question.

Comment: Mark, may you please be more specific?

Comment: You are only describing performance of the generic use case of string vs string builder for concatenation (eg in a loop), but the OP is asking about using `replace` on a `StringBuilder` vs `String`.

Comment: No, I wrote "modification" and "multiple operations" and I meant it so.